# how to specify literal value in linq union

Tags: sql, linq

I have the following SQL query, note I want the literal value '0' in the second
field in the second SELECT statement from the ItemSale table.
How do I express this in LINQ?
I get the error message 'Invalid anonymous type member declarator'.

```
SELECT BranchNumber,QuantitySold
FROM Department 
UNION
SELECT BranchNumber,0
FROM ItemSale
```

How to express the '0' in LINQ?

```
var unionQuery = (from dept in Department
                            select new
                            {
                                dept.BranchNumber,
                                dept.QuantitySold,
                            })
                            .Concat(from item in ItemSale
                               select new
                               {
                                   item.BranchNumber,
                                   0
                               });
```

Comment: sorry, placed comment in wrong spot.

Answer (score 1):

In LINQ, the field has to have a name that matches the corresponding field in the other anonymous type.

```
select new
{
   item.BranchNumber,
   QuantitySold=0
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this just causes the following error: The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Queryable.Concat<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Perhaps the types are mismatched. Try casting the `0` to whatever type `dept.QuantitySold` is.

Comment: If it's a double, then just use `0.0`.